# appcfg.py upload_data require auth in Mac OSX

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have Google App SDK on Mac OSX 1.4.11, all python environment are OK. I try to upload data from manually generated .csv using appcfg.py. When upload directly to Google appspot.com all succeed.
Just to perform upload data locally it fail for authentication reason as generated below:

```
Application: myapplication; version: 1.
Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20100626.105711
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20100626.105711.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to /http//localhost:8080/remote_api
[ERROR   ] Exception during authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 3169, in Run
    self.request_manager.Authenticate()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1178, in Authenticate
    remote_api_stub.MaybeInvokeAuthentication()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 542, in MaybeInvokeAuthentication
    datastore_stub._server.Send(datastore_stub._path, payload=None)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 346, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 387, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 498, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 425, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 360, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 506, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
[INFO    ] Authentication Failed
```

Any advise of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an internal server error on the development server. Check the development server logs for a traceback.